# Re-apply for a Job Position

Tags: applications

In the last few months, I applied for a Programmer position, got the interview, and after few weeks, heard nothing. I wrote a follow up email letter to the HR, and another a text message (the same way they messaged me to invite me to the interview) and still got no response.

After few more weeks, I got an email alert from a job board (not the same job board as before) saying that exactly the same position is open and hiring. I am very interested in this position since the job description and requirements suited my skills and interest, plus the job vacancy itself is very attractive (salary wise).

Is it safe to apply for this job again? In your own opinion, does the fact that HR never responds to your emails or follow up letters really mean they rejected my candidature? Is it safe to reapply for the job, even thought you don't know for sure if you are rejected? What is the best way?

Comment: All it cost you is a bit of printing and postage. The worst the'll do is discard the application.  Go for it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no need of to reapply. Due to the fact that last time they didn't respond you, you can see how the company works, and they are not professional people.

If you did reapply and get selected now, then you will find the company frustrating after few months. because in an unprofessional environment, it's very tough to work.

This is from my own personal experience, I too have worked with a company like this.

They were unprofessional, so I also was frustrated.

That's why I am suggesting that you don't bother.

Comment: I updated the answer to improve the English, hopefully haven't changed you meaning.

Comment: It is a poor answer though, how does the fact HR didn't respond indicate the whole company is unprofessional (as actually this is common in recruitment)?  Also, how do you link the experience you had to what would generally happen, and exactly what was "frustrating" about it.

Comment: oh and don't spam by putting links into answers for your employer, you'll get banned pretty quickly.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager: Something being common doesn't make it professional. At the resume stage, I don't have a problem with not responding (companies can get a ridiculously large number of those, after all), but I feel that if you had enough time to set aside to interview them, then you have 5 minutes to send a simple "Thanks, but no thanks" email (it could even be a stock email), and to not do so is unprofessional. I do agree, though, that professionalism (or lack thereof) in HR means nothing about the company as a whole.

Comment: It seems to me that if these 'unprofessional' work environments exist, some people must enjoy working in such environments.

Answer (score 2):

Many companies will have a policy not to interview or hire a candidate if the candidate has been through the interview process in the recent six months or three months. Even if you have been through the interview second time, HR will verify of the recent six months history and can reject you just before releasing the offer letter.

Comment: The OP is in the Philippines, how is a relieving letter (an India specific thing) relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You are wasting your time reapplying.  If you had just applied and heard nothing, I'd suggest tweaking the CV/Resume and trying again, but the fact you've been through the interview process means you were a no-hire, and reapplying will just be rejected.

Unfortunately this is common worldwide in recruitment, if you are a prospect they will keep the lines of communication open, as soon as you are not it can be impossible to get any response.

As an example I once interviewed for a a very senior role in a mutinational, multiple stages over a month, finally flown across the country to head office for final stage (at their expense).  Whatever didn't gel I never found out, they went silent post interview, and, after a suitable amount of effort to get closure, I just moved on to the next prospect.

As a hiring manager I'd say it can often be a fear of giving you feedback, in case you take offence at their reasons (which may be gut feel anyway) and lawyer up, so their best solution is to say nothing.  I'd give it at least 6 months to a year before trying them again.